# Trouble achieving css gradient overlay

Tags: css, gradient

[image: Gradient]

I'm trying to achieve the above gradient (sorry for the small picture).  I initially tried using just CSS3 via the linear-gradient property, but for some reason the overlay did not blend into the page background property.  I'm basically looking for a way to fade the content of a div (potentially white text, or images) into a #252525 background color.

I tried this approach:
    http://dabblet.com/gist/6340486

```
body {
  background: #252525;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

div:after {
  background: #252525;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.0000), rgba(37, 37, 37, 1));
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute
}
```

But all this seemed to achieve was a strangely rendered div with various shades of gray overlaying my content.

Comment: Please create a fiddle or sketch, or show what code you have tried so we can better help you.

Comment: Please do not use external links that can change. This devalues your questions for future users if that resource goes away.

Comment: I updated the question with some real code.

Comment: Do you mean like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ58e/)?

Answer (score 4):

Try this mate ...

```
div:after {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.0000), rgba(37, 37, 37, 1));
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
content: " ";
position: absolute
}
```